# tkinter gif not moving, can tkinter display moving pictures?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, animated-gif

My gif picture is not moving in tkinter. Help please. Thank you

```
canvas = Canvas(width = 450, height = 450, bg = 'white')
canvas.grid(row=2, column=0,sticky = 'W')
gif = PhotoImage(file = "picture.gif")
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = gif, anchor = NW)
mainloop()
```

Comment: why do you think your gif should be moving? Your code isn't moving it anywhere, it's just putting it in one spot? Are you saying you have an animated gif and it isn't being animated?

Comment: its is an animated gif and tis not being animated

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter does not support animated gifs.

The tk photo image class supports creating an image from each of the sub-images of an animated gif, and with that you can create your own animation. I don't know of any examples in python, but the tcl/tk version can be seen here: http://wiki.tcl.tk/4882